# Swagger-ui 3.x not creating index.html after building dist

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger-ui, swagger-node-express

I'm trying to using [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) to document my node.js API. I have cloned the latest repository (3.x) into my repository. When i run `sudo npm run build` to create the dist folder, it generates several files but it doesn't create index.html . The files it is generating are:

*swagger-ui.css,swagger-ui.css.map, swagger-ui.js, swagger-ui.js.map, swagger-ui-bundle.js, swagger-ui-bundle.js.map, swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js, swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.map*

`sudo npm run dev`  runs the development server correctly.